# DRY for Typescript Class Serialization

Tags: typescript, dry

Implementing persistance in my typescript app.

```
interface Store {
  readItem(id:string): Promise<object>;
  writeItem(data: object): Promise<bool>;
}

interface Storable {
   serialize(): object;
   deserialize(data: object): void;
}
```

In all my classes I have to do the following pattern:

```
class MyStorableClass implements Storable {
   id: string;
   foo: string;
   bar: string; 
   baz: number;

   constructor(id: string, foo: string, bar: string, baz: number) {
     this.id = id;
     this.foo = foo;
     this.bar = bar;
     this.baz = baz;
   }
   
   serialize(): object {
     return {
        id: this.id;
        foo: this.foo,
        bar: this.bar,
        baz: this.baz
     };
   }

   deserialize(data: object) {
      this.id = data.id;
      this.foo = data.foo;
      this.bar = data.bar;
      this.baz = data.baz;
   }
}

// example usage:

const myClass = new MyStorableClass("my-first-object","1","2",3);
const myStore = new MyStore();

await myStore.writeItem(myClass.toObject());
const myClass2 = new MyStorableClass("my-second-object","a","b",5);
const data = await myStore.readItem("my-first-object");
myClass2.fromObject(data);
console.log(myClass2.id); //"my-first-object"
```

Is there a way DRY up the constructor and de/serialize methods?

Also if there was a smarter way to provide typesafety for `read/writeItem` I would prefer to use that.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to clarify/fix: ① How does `Store` interact with your code? It doesn't seem to be referenced anywhere. ② You have some interface methods with no return types and that's a syntax error; do you want them to return `void`?

Comment: I think if we’re using plain TypeScript and not some existing library or code generation tool, there’s going to be a limit to how DRY you can be.  You’ll probably have to mention the key names a few times, especially if the classes will have any own enumerable properties that should *not* be serialized, and if you need to keep the constructor as accepting some ordered list of args instead of a single object like `deserialize()` accepts. Are you interested in seeing such a solution or is it not worth the caveats?

Comment: Edits added. If there is a standard library for marshingling data, or using decorators, I would be interested in it.

Comment: I throw down the challenge to you to not use classes - you’ve got POJO’s there. If you want to implement behaviours, create functions that take these types and performs operations, as opposed to adding instance methods. Writing them as classes makes things extremely verbose where as just specifying them as types makes things really simple. If you need to validate inputted data is the type you expect it to be before “marshaling” it - pass it to one of the hundred open source schema validation libraries

Comment: • `bool` isn’t a thing; presumably you mean `boolean`. It’s always helpful for example code to be tested in an IDE before being posted, so you’re sure you’re not bringing up unrelated problems. • How do you imagine `Store` knowing the types of the values at particular `id`s? • I don’t personally know anything about libraries so I’ll probably disengage.  Good luck!

Comment: @AdamJenkins Ah okay, if I understand what you are suggesting--since read/write work on POJO's, build the model data around pojo's as well as functions to implement the behavior I need.

Comment: @Alan - yes. It's more of a preference to be honest, but when you look at all the boilerplate you got there, it all goes away if you just use types and plain objects, and then replace the concept of "methods" with pure functions that operate on your plain objects. If I can get ahead of myself - don't mutate things! Mutation isn't bad necessarily, but there's no simpler thing you can have when writing code than a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)